# Replace DIV contents with DIV contents JavaScript (No jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, css, sharepoint-2007

I am currently working on a form for a page in MOSS 2007 and am forced to use a lot of JavaScript in place of CSS3 and jQuery due to government restrictions. I come from the C# world and JavaScript is still somewhat new to me.

My current objective is to replace the contents of a stationary div element with the contents of another that is hidden on the page. I'm coming to my wits end trying resolve this only remaining issue on this page. Currently I'm using a simple (pseudo: doc.getbyid(id).innerhtml = newdiv) to replace the contents of the div, now my two theories are that either 1) the onclick event isn't calling the function, or 2) the replace just isn't working.

```js
(function() {
 document.getElementById("currentSlide").innerHtml = document.getElementById("contactSlide").innerHtml;
})();

var eIDs = [ "contactSlide", "typeSlide", "permissionsSlide", "bugReportSlide" ];

function nextSlide(id) {
 document.getElementById("currentSlide").innerHtml = document.getElementById(eIDs[id]).innerHtml;
}
```

```css
#msform {
 width: 400px;
 margin: 50px auto;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
}
#msform .fsDiv {
 background: white;
 border: 0 none;
 border-radius: 3px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 padding: 20px 30px;
 width: 80%;
 margin: 0 10%;
 position: relative;
}
#msform .fsDiv:not(:first-of-type) {
 display: none;
}
#msform input, #msform textarea {
 padding: 15px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 width: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: montserrat;
 color: #2C3E50;
 font-size: 13px;
}
#msform .action-button {
 width: 100px;
 background: #27AE60;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: white;
 border: 0 none;
 border-radius: 1px;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 10px 5px;
 margin: 10px 5px;
}
#msform .action-button:hover, #msform .action-button:focus {
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
}
.title {
 font-size: 15px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #2C3E50;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.subtitle {
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #666;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#progressbar {
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 overflow: hidden;
 counter-reset: step;
}
#progressbar li {
 list-style-type: none;
 color: black;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 9px;
 width: 33.33%;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
}
#progressbar li:before {
 content: counter(step);
 counter-increment: step;
 width: 20px;
 line-height: 20px;
 display: block;
 font-size: 10px;
 color: #333;
 background: white;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}
#progressbar li:after {
 content: '';
 width: 100%;
 height: 2px;
 background: white;
 position: absolute;
 left: -50%;
 top: 9px;
 z-index: -1;
}
#progressbar li:first-child:after {
 content: none; 
}
#progressbar li.active:before,  #progressbar li.active:after{
 background: #27AE60;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
 <div id="msform">
    <ul id="progressbar">
      <li class="active">Contact Information</li>
      <li>Request Type</li>
      <li>Details</li>
    </ul>
      <div id="currentSlide" class="fsDiv"></div>
    <div id="contactSlide" class="fsDiv">
      <h2 class="title">Contact Information</h2>
      <h3 class="subtitle">Please supply your contact information.</h3>
      <input type="text" name="contName" placeholder="Last Name, First Name" />
      <input type="text" name="contNum" placeholder="Phone Number" />
      <input type="text" name="contEma" placeholder="E-Mail" />
      <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </div>
    <div id="typeSlide" class="fsDiv">
      <h2 class="fs-title">Request Type</h2>
      <h3 class="fs-subtitle">What type of request would you like to make?</h3>
      <span>Type: <select name="ddlTypes">
    <option>Permissions</option>
    <option>Report Bug</option>
   </select></span>
      <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
      <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </div>
    <div id="permissionStage" class="fsDiv">
      <h2 class="title">Permissions Request</h2>
      <h3 class="subtitle">Please supply details about your request.</h3>
      <input type="text" name="permName" placeholder="Last Name, First Name" />
      <span>Permission Level Needed: <select name="ddlPermissions">
    <option>Viewer</option>
    <option>Member</option>
    <option>Administrator</option>
   </select></span>
      <input type="text" name="permReason" placeholder="Reason For Permission Level" />
      <input type="text" name="permLink" placeholder="Link To Area Where Access Is Needed" />
      <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
    </div>
    <div id="bugReportSlide" class="fsDiv">
      <h2 class="title">Report An Issue</h2>
      <h3 class="subtitle">Please provide some details about the issue.</h3>
      <input type="text" name="bugLocation" placeholder="Link To Page" />
      <input type="text" name="bugDescription" placeholder="What Is Happening?" />
      <span>Severity: <select name="ddlSeverity">
    <option>Low</option>
    <option>Medium</option>
    <option>High</option>
    <option>Critical</option>
   </select></span>
      <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
      <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
    </div>
 </div>
```

The only other thing I can think to do is to store the inner html in a var and just assigning it as needed. Please help!

Comment: I also work for government clients sometimes too - there should be no restriction on hosting jquery on your server; grabbing it from an external source is a no-no though.

Comment: The issue here is getting people to handle that and get it on the server. It took me a month from date of hire to even get a computer to work on. Three more months before I could actually start coding. Still don't have all the tools I need, not even VS. I have no idea how long it's going to take them to get jQuery on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things why it's not working

1. change `innerHtml` to `innerHTML`
2. add a `load` handler so DOM is ready before you target its elements

*I also chose to drop the unnecessary `document.getElementById()` statement and simpy call the `nextSlide` function with its first item index*

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
  nextSlide(0);
})

var eIDs = [ "contactSlide", "typeSlide", "permissionsSlide", "bugReportSlide" ];

function nextSlide(id) {
 document.getElementById("currentSlide").innerHTML = document.getElementById(eIDs[id]).innerHTML;
}
```

```css
#msform {
 width: 400px;
 margin: 50px auto;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
}
#msform .fsDiv {
 background: white;
 border: 0 none;
 border-radius: 3px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 padding: 20px 30px;
 width: 80%;
 margin: 0 10%;
 position: relative;
}
#msform .fsDiv:not(:first-of-type) {
 display: none;
}
#msform input, #msform textarea {
 padding: 15px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 width: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: montserrat;
 color: #2C3E50;
 font-size: 13px;
}
#msform .action-button {
 width: 100px;
 background: #27AE60;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: white;
 border: 0 none;
 border-radius: 1px;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 10px 5px;
 margin: 10px 5px;
}
#msform .action-button:hover, #msform .action-button:focus {
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
}
.title {
 font-size: 15px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #2C3E50;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.subtitle {
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #666;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#progressbar {
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 overflow: hidden;
 counter-reset: step;
}
#progressbar li {
 list-style-type: none;
 color: black;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 9px;
 width: 33.33%;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
}
#progressbar li:before {
 content: counter(step);
 counter-increment: step;
 width: 20px;
 line-height: 20px;
 display: block;
 font-size: 10px;
 color: #333;
 background: white;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}
#progressbar li:after {
 content: '';
 width: 100%;
 height: 2px;
 background: white;
 position: absolute;
 left: -50%;
 top: 9px;
 z-index: -1;
}
#progressbar li:first-child:after {
 content: none; 
}
#progressbar li.active:before,  #progressbar li.active:after{
 background: #27AE60;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="msform">
    <ul id="progressbar">
      <li class="active">Contact Information</li>
      <li>Request Type</li>
      <li>Details</li>
    </ul>
      <div id="currentSlide" class="fsDiv"></div>
    <div id="contactSlide" class="fsDiv">
      <h2 class="title">Contact Information</h2>
      <h3 class="subtitle">Please supply your contact information.</h3>
      <input type="text" name="contName" placeholder="Last Name, First Name" />
      <input type="text" name="contNum" placeholder="Phone Number" />
      <input type="text" name="contEma" placeholder="E-Mail" />
      <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </div>
    <div id="typeSlide" class="fsDiv">
      <h2 class="fs-title">Request Type</h2>
      <h3 class="fs-subtitle">What type of request would you like to make?</h3>
      <span>Type: <select name="ddlTypes">
    <option>Permissions</option>
    <option>Report Bug</option>
   </select></span>
      <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
      <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </div>
    <div id="permissionStage" class="fsDiv">
      <h2 class="title">Permissions Request</h2>
      <h3 class="subtitle">Please supply details about your request.</h3>
      <input type="text" name="permName" placeholder="Last Name, First Name" />
      <span>Permission Level Needed: <select name="ddlPermissions">
    <option>Viewer</option>
    <option>Member</option>
    <option>Administrator</option>
   </select></span>
      <input type="text" name="permReason" placeholder="Reason For Permission Level" />
      <input type="text" name="permLink" placeholder="Link To Area Where Access Is Needed" />
      <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
    </div>
    <div id="bugReportSlide" class="fsDiv">
      <h2 class="title">Report An Issue</h2>
      <h3 class="subtitle">Please provide some details about the issue.</h3>
      <input type="text" name="bugLocation" placeholder="Link To Page" />
      <input type="text" name="bugDescription" placeholder="What Is Happening?" />
      <span>Severity: <select name="ddlSeverity">
    <option>Low</option>
    <option>Medium</option>
    <option>High</option>
    <option>Critical</option>
   </select></span>
      <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
      <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is ok, but replace innerHtml with innerHTML, JavaScript is case sensitive.

```
(function() {
    document.getElementById("currentSlide").innerHTML = document.getElementById("contactSlide").innerHTML;
})();

var eIDs [ "contactSlide", "typeSlide", "permissionsSlide", "bugReportSlide" ];

function nextSlide(var id) {
    document.getElementById("currentSlide").innerHTML = document.getElementById(eIDs[id]).innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, C# is too, and I figured JavaScript was as well. However unfortunately that didn't work either. The page still loads with initial empty div so there's no next button, so at this point, how do I get that to work without jQuery so I can move to the next issue if one arises. Please keep in mind things like document.ready and bound events from markup are not allowed. Also, $ is not allowed either somehow?

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function() {
 document.getElementById("currentSlide").innerHTML = document.getElementById("contactSlide").innerHTML;
})();

var eIDs = [ "contactSlide", "typeSlide", "permissionsSlide", "bugReportSlide" ];

function nextSlide(id) {
 document.getElementById("currentSlide").innerHTML = document.getElementById(eIDs[id]).innerHTML;
}
```

```css
#msform {
 width: 400px;
 margin: 50px auto;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
}
#msform .fsDiv {
 background: white;
 border: 0 none;
 border-radius: 3px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 padding: 20px 30px;
 width: 80%;
 margin: 0 10%;
 position: relative;
}
#msform .fsDiv:not(:first-of-type) {
 display: none;
}
#msform input, #msform textarea {
 padding: 15px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 width: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: montserrat;
 color: #2C3E50;
 font-size: 13px;
}
#msform .action-button {
 width: 100px;
 background: #27AE60;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: white;
 border: 0 none;
 border-radius: 1px;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 10px 5px;
 margin: 10px 5px;
}
#msform .action-button:hover, #msform .action-button:focus {
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
}
.title {
 font-size: 15px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #2C3E50;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.subtitle {
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #666;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#progressbar {
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 overflow: hidden;
 counter-reset: step;
}
#progressbar li {
 list-style-type: none;
 color: black;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 9px;
 width: 33.33%;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
}
#progressbar li:before {
 content: counter(step);
 counter-increment: step;
 width: 20px;
 line-height: 20px;
 display: block;
 font-size: 10px;
 color: #333;
 background: white;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}
#progressbar li:after {
 content: '';
 width: 100%;
 height: 2px;
 background: white;
 position: absolute;
 left: -50%;
 top: 9px;
 z-index: -1;
}
#progressbar li:first-child:after {
 content: none; 
}
#progressbar li.active:before,  #progressbar li.active:after{
 background: #27AE60;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
 <div id="msform">
    <ul id="progressbar">
      <li class="active">Contact Information</li>
      <li>Request Type</li>
      <li>Details</li>
    </ul>
      <div id="currentSlide" class="fsDiv"></div>
    <div id="contactSlide" class="fsDiv">
      <h2 class="title">Contact Information</h2>
      <h3 class="subtitle">Please supply your contact information.</h3>
      <input type="text" name="contName" placeholder="Last Name, First Name" />
      <input type="text" name="contNum" placeholder="Phone Number" />
      <input type="text" name="contEma" placeholder="E-Mail" />
      <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </div>
    <div id="typeSlide" class="fsDiv">
      <h2 class="fs-title">Request Type</h2>
      <h3 class="fs-subtitle">What type of request would you like to make?</h3>
      <span>Type: <select name="ddlTypes">
    <option>Permissions</option>
    <option>Report Bug</option>
   </select></span>
      <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
      <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </div>
    <div id="permissionStage" class="fsDiv">
      <h2 class="title">Permissions Request</h2>
      <h3 class="subtitle">Please supply details about your request.</h3>
      <input type="text" name="permName" placeholder="Last Name, First Name" />
      <span>Permission Level Needed: <select name="ddlPermissions">
    <option>Viewer</option>
    <option>Member</option>
    <option>Administrator</option>
   </select></span>
      <input type="text" name="permReason" placeholder="Reason For Permission Level" />
      <input type="text" name="permLink" placeholder="Link To Area Where Access Is Needed" />
      <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
    </div>
    <div id="bugReportSlide" class="fsDiv">
      <h2 class="title">Report An Issue</h2>
      <h3 class="subtitle">Please provide some details about the issue.</h3>
      <input type="text" name="bugLocation" placeholder="Link To Page" />
      <input type="text" name="bugDescription" placeholder="What Is Happening?" />
      <span>Severity: <select name="ddlSeverity">
    <option>Low</option>
    <option>Medium</option>
    <option>High</option>
    <option>Critical</option>
   </select></span>
      <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
      <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
    </div>
 </div>
```

You had an issue with the param in your nextSlide function, you were passing `var id`, when it should just be `id`. and your `var eIDs` was missing an `=` so your array was never declared in the variable. the gentleman above is still using the incorrect code. Do you have a click handler? can we see it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with placement of the script itself; moved to the end of the body and worked like a charm! The little issues such as innerHTML and the equals sign for eids and the var id were just little oversights; of course I had to add the additional handlers for onclick once I got the load to work. It's now working like a charm. Thank you all for being such great help!

Comment: The issue is not the placement, it is whether it runs before or after the DOM is ready, which I explained in my answer.